# ReactGA.initialize must be called first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, server-side-rendering, react-ga

I am getting the following warning multiple times (for multiple pages) despite me initializing at the root of my app.  This makes me wonder if google analytics is even working properly?
`[react-ga] ReactGA.initialize must be called first or GoogleAnalytics should be loaded manually`

I am using ReactGA to handle my google analytics tags, and I cannot get it to work.  According to the documentation and a handful of other questions about this online, all I need to do is insert this at my application root:

App.js:

```js
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
ReactGA.initialize('G-xxxxxxxxxx');

const app = () => (
    // Root level components here, like routing and navigation
)
```

I am using Server Side Rendering, so I am making sure the window object exists before tracking.  This line is put at the end of my imports on each of my pages:

example page.js:

```js
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
if (typeof(window) !== 'undefined') {
    ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
}

function page() {
    return(<div className="page">Hello, World</div>)
}

export default page;
```

At this point, there isn't a lot of information on how to set up Google Analytics for SSR applications, so I'm not entirely sure what I need to do to get this working.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found the solution after a lot of tinkering with potential solutions.  Since pageview was being fired before initialize could finish, I tired delaying pageview as much as I could by placing it in `componentDidMount()`.  That implementation looks like this:

App.js:

```js
//imports
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
ReactGA.initialize('UA-xxxxxxxxx-x');

const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <Navigation />
            
    <AppRouting />
  </div>
);
```

Page.js:

```js
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

class MyPage extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Component />
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In functional components the same can be done using the `useEffect` hook

```
useEffect(() => {
 ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
}, ['your dep'])
```